# How do I set up a bridge on Ubuntu GNOME 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I found a guide for setting up a bridge in Fedora and was trying this:

```
$ nmcli connection delete p33p1
$ nmcli connection add con-name br0 type bridge ifname br0 autoconnect yes
$ nmcli connection add con-name p33p1 type bridge-slave ifname p33p1 master br0 autoconnect yes
```

I found that

```
$ nmcli con delete uuid [uuid here]
```

accomplished the first step.  `nmcli connection` does not have an 'add' action in this distribution.

How do I do the 2nd and 3rd steps?

Context:  I am trying to set up a virtual machine.  I believe this is a necessary step for the VM to access my network and the Internet.  Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I am almost too embarrassed to post this...

When I first started out, I went to System Settings - Network and found no way there to do anything like this.

This morning, I discovered there is an application under Sundry called Network Connections.  This application makes this process SUPER easy and straight forward.

As a Linux newbie, why that is under "sundry" is beyond me...

Info added Jun 5, 2014:

Unfortunately this does not seem to work.  Following [this guide](http://avi.alkalay.net/2014/01/fedora-20-virtualization-networkmanager-native-bridge.html), and it's subsequent links, it appears that this will not work until network manager 0.9.9.0 --not yet available for Ubuntu.

I have:
kernel: 3.13.0-27-generic
network manager: 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7
libnl3: libnl-3-200 v 3.2.21-1

Here is how I have proceeded:

I use dhcp to get my pc's ip address.

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

replace everything with:

```
#tell network manager to leave eth0 alone
iface eth0 inet manual

# enable loopback interface
#auto lo
#iface lo inet loopback

# start bridge on boot
auto br0

#bridge settings

iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_waitport 0    # no delay before a port becomes available
    bridge_fd 0        # no forwarding delay

sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf

append this:

# Disable netfilter disabled on all bridges
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

WARNING, you will loose your connection at this step:

Run nm-connection and delete all devices there.

Reboot.

nm-applet in system tray says network is not connected, but it is wrong. try accessing a web page.

This is a work in progress...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I gues this may help.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth1 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
  bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

or

visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge